# How to serialize List collection object in Hadoop?

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop

Is there a way to serialize java collections in Hadoop?

The `Writable` interface is for Java primitives only. I have following class attributes.

```
private String keywords;
private List<Status> tweets;
private long queryTime = 0;

public TweetStatus(String keys, List<Status> tweets, long queryTime){
    this.keywords = keys;
    this.tweets = tweets;
    this.queryTime = queryTime;
}
```

How I can serialize `List` object?

Comment: Why can't you break down `Status` into a set of primitives that you can turn into a `Writable`?

Comment: What is the definition of `Status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `Writable` interface is for Java primitives only.

Right. Basically you need to break down your object into a sequence of objects that you can serialize.

So, from first principles, to serialize a list you need to serialize the size of the list and then serialize each element of the list. This way, when you need to deserialize, you know how many elements you need to deserialize.

Something like this should get you on the write (pun!) track:

```
class TweetStatusWritable implements Writable {
    private String keywords;
    private List<Status> tweets;
    private long queryTime;

    // add getters for the above three fields

    public void readFields(DataInput in) {
        this.keywords = in.readUTF();
        int size = in.readInt();
        this.tweets = new List<Status>();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Status status = // deserialize an instance of Status
            tweets.add(status);
        }
        this.queryTime = in.readLong();
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) {
        out.writeUTF(this.keywords);
        out.writeInt(this.tweets.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < this.tweets.size(); i++) {
             // serialize tweets[i] onto out
        }       
        out.writeLong(queryTime);
    }

    public TweetStatusWritable(
        String keywords,
        List<Status> tweets,
        long queryTime
    ) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.tweets = tweets;
        this.queryTime = queryTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example what does the comment "// serialize tweets[i] onto out" mean. Here the data type for the List tweets is a custom data type "Status". If it were a primitive data type such as "Long", would writing "out.writeLong(tweets[i]);" be correct to serialize tweets onto out?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ArrayWritable.  It lets you serialize an array of instances (all of the same type).  You could build one of those from your List

Comment: MapWritable is even better than ArrayWritable https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapWritable.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of serialization stuff ahead, you might find [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) useful.